# Vagrantfile - multible vm showing up with the same hostname

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I've created a Vagrantfile which launches two vm's, an ubuntu and a centos. I've stated in the Vagrantfile the hostname of both vm's but when I run vagrant up they both come up with the same hostname of **centos90**.

What am I doing wrong here.

```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.define "ub80" do |ub80|
  ub80.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.hostname = "ubuntu80"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.80"
end

config.vm.define "cos90" do |cos90|
  cos90.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.hostname = "centos90"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.90"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

me again!

syntax was wrong I was using config.vm.xxx for configurations instead of the name given in the `config.vm.define` command.

Below is the corect syntax:

```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.define "ub80" do |ub80|
  ub80.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  ub80.vm.hostname = "ubuntu80"
  ub80.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.80"
end

config.vm.define "cos90" do |cos90|
  cos90.vm.box = "centos/7"
  cos90.vm.hostname = "centos90"
  cos90.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.90"
end
```